# Not able to forward Pfsense 2.4.4 Squid log to elk

Tags: squid, pfsense

I have tried a couple of options so far but not able to forward logs to my elk server.

Can someone please help me on this and guide me what configuration changes I have to make in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding below in "Custom Options (Before Auth)" in Advance option of Squid Proxy server.

access_log udp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:514 squid